# Pyqt5 qtablewidget detect when a cell changes

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I have a tableWidget on my Pyqt5 app on Python. The issue is that I am trying to connect to the calculadora function when a specific cell changes, so i have two questions:

- What is the difference between  .cellChanged and itemChanged.?

-Right now i am using this:

```
self.ui.tableWidget_Calculadora.itemChanged.connect(self.calculadora)

def calculadora_1(self):
      print("Cell 1,1 Changes")
```

But i want to be more specific and connect when for example the cell (1,1) changes, not any cell, what my code currently does.

I tried using this:

```
self.ui.tableWidget_Calculadora.itemChanged(1,1).connect(self.calculadora)
```

But I got this error:

```
TypeError: native Qt signal is not callable
```

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to filter on slot based on the QTableWidget that transmits the signal:

```py
self.ui.tableWidget_Calculadora.itemChanged.connect(self.calculadora)
```

```py
def calculadora_1(self, item):
      if item.row() == 1 and item.column() == 1:
          print("Cell 1,1 Changes")
```